# Facebook javascript integration with RoR does not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

Facebook login using the Javascript FB.getLoginStatus works in one case and does not work in anther.

This works:

```
//view
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      alert(response.name + " " + response.id);
      name1 = response.name;
      uid1 = response.id;
    });
    // var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    // var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
}
</script>

<%= content_for :body_attributes, "onload='f1();'" %>
```

This does not work

```
// view
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1() {
    // same definition as above
    }
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> {
f1()
    }
 </script>
```

I do not understand why the second code does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
{
    f1()
}
 </script>
```

Remove the braces and add a semicolon and you should be ok:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    f1();
 </script>
```

Comment: OK. When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Do you get errors? Did you look at the console?

Comment: The alert() statement doesn't display the variables: name1 and uid1

Comment: Doesn't it display response.name and response.uid which are the same as name1 and uid1.

Comment: Doesn't FB.api have to be trigged by an event?

Comment: Did you _check_ your browser’s error console? (Or let’s maybe start one step lower – do you even know where to find it …?)

Answer (score 0):

> This works:

```
//view
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1 {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
```

Hard to believe that this should work – because that’s *not* how you define a function in JavaScript. It’s missing the round brackets () after the function name.

> [from comments] Doesn't FB.api have to be trigged by an event?

No, it doesn’t – it can be called from anywhere.

Just with methods that will (/might) create a popup window (FB.login, FB.ui) it is usually better to call them on user interaction such as a click, because otherwise modern browser’s popup blockers with default settings are likely to suppress the popup.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your help. The function definition was a typo in the above code but not in my working version. I'm sorry. I made the edits.The FB.api call does not work in the second scenario. I seem to remember reading somewhere that it has to be triggered. Thanks again!

Comment: Rereading your comment @CBroe , are you saying that the popup blockers may be responsible for the behavior of case 2? Even though popup windows are not involved. Thanks!

Comment: Please be more careful with your problem descriptions in the future, because it helps not getting sidetracked in they way we just did. That said, is the JS SDK even loaded and initialized properly in the second scenario, at that point where you call your function …?

Comment: Thanks@CBroe! I'll do my best! It is loaded and initialized in exactly the same way as case1.